# What data we get from google adsense management api?

Tags: adsense

I already know we can get these data: PAGE_VIEWS, AD_REQUESTS, MATCHED_AD_REQUESTS, INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS

but is there more? Like bank account pending or ready, payment due this month etc...

I can hardly find this on google. I hope somebody with advance knowledge can help.